# Typo3 Carousel DCE Optimize Code

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to optimize my working carousel and I want to use for:each.

Does anyone maybe see my error?

[Working Quote Code](https://gist.github.com/DarthKeks/f5b3c9c26f05f3a8dfbf127dee9f9b64)

[New not working Quote Code](https://gist.github.com/DarthKeks/04bd72aa5374bb0dd925533278b167d1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">

    <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <f:for each="{field.person}" as="person" iteration=“iterator“>
                  <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="{iterator.index}" {'class="active"'->f:if(condition:iterator.isFirst)}></li>
        </f:for>
    </ol>

    <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <f:for each="{field.person}" as="person" iteration=“iterator“>
            <!-- Quote {iterator.index -->
            <div class="item {'active'->f:if(condition:iterator.isFirst)}">
                <blockquote>
                    <f:format.html>{person.expert}</f:format.html>
                    <small>{person.expertName}</small>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </f:for>
    </div>

    <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
    <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control">
        <span style="top: 25%;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control">
        <span style="top: 25%;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```